# css pre code highlight doesn't work in Atom

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

I'm using markdown-themeable-pdf package in Atom to produce pdf files.
Using custom css to produce code style as I like. I wrote this:

```
  code, tt {
  margin: 0 2px;
  font-family: YaHei Consolas Hybrid;
  color: #333767;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px; }

pre code {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;custom code highlight in atom markdown
  white-space: pre;
  border: none;
  background: transparent; }

.highlight pre {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px; }

pre {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: #333767;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px; }

  pre code, pre tt {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none; }
```

but it doesn't work with code highlight theme:

[image]

When using like

````
```css

```
````

There would be another box inside and adjusting `.highlight pre` is useless.

How to adjust highlight code?

Answer (score 1):

Finished.

This is because for highlight code, markdown-themeable-pdf uses another `.css` file in `.atom\packages\markdown-themeable-pdf\node_modules\highlight.js\styles`

Change the highlight theme here would produce pdf just fine.

Comment: For people who can read Chinese, I wrote a blog about this. [click here](https://www.forenewhan.science/programming/atom_markdown_to_pdf/)